# Gives a fixed answer to ansible prompt

Tags: bash, ansible

Ansible, when driven by a user with MFA, needs to give the verification code asked by sshd from the target host. I can type it in, but when a playbooks runs for many hosts, I would need to type as many times as my hosts.

I am looking for something like:

```
yes 101010 | ansible-playbooks playbook.yaml
```

where `101010` is the verification code (which is the same for all the hosts).

Answer (score 1):

The [ansible](/questions/tagged/ansible) commands can handle variable arguments with the `-e` switch.

By example :

```
ansible [...] -e verif=101010
```

The variable `verif` will be accessible in ansible code

Comment: Thank you for your time. The matter is the verification code is on the same level as the ssh password (-k switch) or the sudo one (-K). It is not a playbook variable, but more a connection parameter. I solved wrapping the `ansible-playbook` command in an `expect` script (the linux utility, not the ansible module).

Comment: Never seen a case where 'expect' is really needed in (close to) 20 years of computer science. Always ssh key pairs was the proper solution

Comment: ;) some people advocate ssh pubkey is not a true 2FA. That's why it might happen a host server requires pubkey + Verification code = 2FA.

Comment: If you hardcode credentials like I see most of the time in your expect script, this is plain wrong at security level. Dunno if it's your use case

Comment: google authenticator verification codes (TOTP) rotate every 30 secs. Even if you hardcode them for a given run, it's not a great risk.

Comment: You have open source OTP generator (`andOTP`) ;)